# Eastern time should be -4 not -5 ? How can I store the timezone offset on my application?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

> I am creating an application that saves the dates on universal time. Later I change the dates according to the timezone that the user specifies.
>
> To save the date I do:

```
 var dateToSaveOnDatabase = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

> If I go to google I verify the utc date to be:

---

[image]

---

> Now on my app I let the user specify the timezone manually with a number. Lets say the user chooses -5 just like on my computer:**

---

[image]

---

> That means that in my code I have

```
var userLocalTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-5)
```

> If I do that `userLocalTime` ends up to be equal to 8:00 PM! The eastern time should be 9:00 PM NOT 8:00 PM :/ . If I google what is the eastern time I get:

[image]

> So my question is why is the eastern time equal to -5 if in reality it is -4 hours away? I am storing the user time zone in a number because the application is used on c# and also on linux. **How should I store the timezone in my application?**

Comment: Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: EST = -5, EDT = -4

Comment: How do I know if I am on Daylight saving time? I want the user to spesify the timezone with a number. What parameters should I collect from him?

Comment: You should instead offer users a choice from [Time Zones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx) since due to Daylight Savings the offset hours won't actually be the exact difference. After a selection is made, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) describes easy conversion to and from UTC time. E.g. `DateTime nowUTC = DateTime.UtcNow; var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"); DateTime nowEast = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowUTC, tz);` gives you EST.

Comment: Side note: if you citing someone (as whole post uses citation formatting) make sure to provide source. Also it may be better to ask author to post question as this one demonstrates strange research as even most basic search (https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+is+my+timezone) would let one to find information about they current time zone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application its best to store the time zone code and then adjust accordingly.  That way you take into account Daylight Saving Time and other weird offsets (not everyone has an offset of an hour, some are 30 or 45 minutes in a few cases).

To convert from UTC to a user's time zone in C# with the time zone code is easy as:

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");

DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```